# Subscribe to the same inbound more than once?

Tags: reactor-netty

In reactor netty, is it possible to subscribe to the same inbound more than once? I notice in `startReceiver` method variable `once` is set to 1 and no other code paths would ever set it back to 0, so any new subscriber trying to subscribe to the inbound would never get the chance to call `onSubscribe`. Is it possible for different subscribers to subscribe to the same inbound? (I understand this is a very rookie or even an invalid question, if it's not even worth asking please let me know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to subscribe more than once for the incoming data.
Reactor Netty does not cache it.
You can use the cache Reactor operator or some other mechanism for caching the incoming data and then manipulate it many times if that's needed.

Comment: I tried share() and got it to work as I want it to. Obviously using cache would also work. Thanks.